# Construct QString from QJsonArray in Qt

Tags: qt, c++11, qstring, qjson, qt5.10

While trying to construct a `QString` from values from a `QJsonArray`, I get the following error:

`error: passing 'const QString' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`.

Dunno where I am getting it wrong in this code:

```
QString <CLASS_NAME>::getData(QString callerValue) {
    QString BASE_URL = "<URL>";

    QString stringToReturn = "";
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, [=](QNetworkReply *reply) {
      QByteArray barr = reply->readAll();
      QJsonParseError jpe;
      QJsonDocument jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(barr, &jpe);
      QJsonArray synonymsArray = jdoc.array();
      foreach (const QJsonValue &jv, synonymsArray) {
        QJsonObject jo = jv.toObject();
        QString s = jo.value("<VALUE>").toString();
        stringToReturn.append(s + ", "); /* ERROR: The error above is from this line... */
      }
    }
    );
    request.setUrl(QUrl(BASE_URL + callerValue));
    manager->get(request);
    return stringToReturn;
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to pass your `stringToReturn` variable to lambda (capture) by reference and not by copy, i.e. use `[&]` instead of `[=]`, because it's const in the lambda body.

Comment: Doing so crashes the app just a few seconds after the GuI appears :(

Comment: You need to investigate why and where it crashes. For example by reading the stack trace or debugging.

Comment: of course it would: `stringToReturn` is a local variable, lambda expression will have a dangling reference in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another classic "I wish the world was synchronous" problem. You can't code that way. The `getData` method can't be written the way you want it to be. `getData` done that way would block, and that's quite wasteful and can lead to interesting problems - not the last of which is horrible UX.

Depending on your application, there would be several possible fixes:

1. redo `getData` in implicit continuation-passing style using coroutines and `co_yield` - this is the future and can be done only on the most recent compilers unless you use hacks such boost coroutines.
2. redo `getData` in explicit continuation-passing style,
3. redo `getData` in lazy style with notification when data is available,
4. have an explicit state machine that deals with progress of your code.

The continuation-passing style requires the least changes. Note the other fixes too - most notably that you shouldn't be using the `QNetworkAccessManager`'s signals: you're interested only in results to this one query, not every query! Catching `QNetworkAccessManager::finished` signal is only useful if you truly have a central point where all or at least most frequent requests can be handled. In such a case, it's a sensible optimization: there is overhead of several `malloc`s to adding the first connection to a hiterto connection-free object.

```
void Class::getData(const QString &urlSuffix, std::function<void(const QString &)> cont) {
  auto const urlString = QStringLiteral("URL%1").arg(urlSuffix);
  QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(urlString));
  auto *reply = m_manager.get(request);
  QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]{
    QString result;
    auto data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonParseError jpe;
    auto jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &jpe);
    auto const synonyms = jdoc.array();
    for (auto &value : synonyms) {
      auto object = value.toObject();
      auto s = object.value("<VALUE">).toString();
      if (!result.isEmpty())
        result.append(QLatin1String(", "))
      result.append(s);
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
    cont(result);
  });
}
```

The lazy style requires the code that uses `getData` to be restartable, and allows continuation-passing as well, as long as the continuation is connected to the signal:

```
class Class : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QString m_cachedData;
  QNetworkAccessManager m_manager{this};
  Q_SIGNAL void dataAvailable(const QString &);
  ...
};

QString Class::getData(const QString &urlSuffix) {
  if (!m_cachedData.isEmpty())
    return m_cachedData;

  auto const urlString = QStringLiteral("URL%1").arg(urlSuffix);
  QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(urlString));
  auto *reply = m_manager.get(request);
  QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]{
    m_cachedData.clear();
    auto data = reply->readAll();
    QJsonParseError jpe;
    auto jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &jpe);
    auto const synonyms = jdoc.array();
    for (auto &value : synonyms) {
      auto object = value.toObject();
      auto s = object.value("<VALUE">).toString();
      if (!m_cachedData.isEmpty())
        m_cachedData.append(QLatin1String(", "))
      m_cachedData.append(s);
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
    emit dataAvailable(m_cachedData);
  });
  return {};
}
```

The state machine formalizes the state progression:

```
class Class : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QStateMachine m_sm{this};
  QNetworkAccessManager m_manager{this};
  QPointer<QNetworkReply> m_reply;
  QState s_idle{&m_sm}, s_busy{&m_sm}, s_done{&m_sm};
  Q_SIGNAL void to_busy();
  void getData(const QString &);
  ...

};

Class::Class(QObject * parent) : QObject(parent) {
  m_sm.setInitialState(&s_idle);
  s_idle.addTransition(this, &Class::to_busy, &s_busy);
  s_done.addTransition(&s_idle);
  m_sm.start();
}

void Class::getData(const QString &urlSuffix) {
  static char const kInit[] = "initialized";
  auto const urlString = QStringLiteral("URL%1").arg(urlSuffix);
  QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(urlString));
  m_reply = m_manager.get(request);
  s_busy.addTransition(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &s_done);
  to_busy();
  if (!s_done.property(kInit).toBool()) {
    QObject::connect(&s_done, &QState::entered, this, [=]{
      QString result;
      auto data = m_reply->readAll();
      QJsonParseError jpe;
      auto jdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data, &jpe);
      auto const synonyms = jdoc.array();
      for (auto &value : synonyms) {
        auto object = value.toObject();
        auto s = object.value("<VALUE">).toString();
        if (!result.isEmpty())
          result.append(QLatin1String(", "))
        result.append(s);
      }
      m_reply->deleteLater();
    });
    s_done.setProperty(kInit, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: oh, did you had working examples handy? That's quite detailed implementation. And yeah, wish to ho synchronous is common sin. Personally i prefer state machine approach. What's UX stands for, though? About this api I always was worried if a race condition would happen - what if signsl is fired before we called connect (wery intensive network exchange). Is that possible scenario?

Comment: It is unclear how to delete `reply` in first example

Comment: @Swift The races don't happen. The implementation prevents it. The examples are written from memory. You might note that they are very short.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it would be wrong: `stringToReturn` is declared as a local variable in `getData`, It would be const if you use `[=]` and it will die at time of function object's call - by `finished` signal , if captured by reference. Lambda expression will have a dangling reference in it.That's bad place to put variable that serves as output for this function object, that variable stops to exist on return from `getData`.

Function object created by lambda expression here is called *after* `getData` returned. it would be called *sometime* when signal is fired as a result of sent request, it's an asynchronous handler. getData IS NOT the caller of lambda in this case. Caller of lambda is  signal-slot system. provided that getData doesn't call lambda explicitly, we have no guarantee that  function object is returned before lifespan of local storage had come to end.

Possible remebdy here is to use a field of `this`, if you can guarantee that `this` ( `<CLASS_NAME>` instance) is still "alive" when `finished()` is fired. essentially this "getData" is unable to return that value unless you would pause it until request is done (which defeats asyncronous approach).

In fact, `finished` would be fired when `QNetworkReply::finished` would be fired, QNetworkAccessManager::get just post request and returns said reply immediately. Signal is fired when you receive data (readyRead is emitted)

Comment: Hm, but `getData()` function returns **a copy** of `stringToReturn` and not a reference to it. So `getData()` defines a variable, lambda modifies it and its copy returned back to the caller - that's absolutely ok.

Comment: What’s a possible remedy, then?

Comment: @ vahancho  lambda here is called _after_ getData  returned. it would be called _sometime_ when signal is fired (as result of sent request), it's an asynchronous handler. getData IS NOT the caller of lambda in this case. caller of lambda is  signal-slot system.

Comment: @vahancho getData would return empty string,. In theory if readyRead will be called before getData return, that can be different, but it's not guaranteed by presented code. It would so for two reasons: lambda can't modify copy-captured objects. 2) lambda isn't called during lifetime of scope of capture.